# How to find out the inverse of an NXN matrix in C

Tags: c, matrix, matrix-inverse

Hi everyone I made some changes in the code so that it's easy to understand, looks what I have so far, I kept the function's prototype at the beginning of the code and it works fine, but it just works fine just when I try a 2x2 matrix because if I try a 3x3, 4x4 or 6x6 matrix it does not works fine the determinant is not calculated right, I guess that's the problem the determinant but I don't know how to solve it. Here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<math.h>


float determinant(int tam,float [][tam]);

void cofactor(int tam,float [][tam]);

void transpose(int tam,float [][tam],float [][tam]);

int validate(){

    int val;
    char *buf = (char *) malloc(10);

    memset(buf,0,10);

    while(fgets(buf, 10, stdin) != NULL ){
        if(buf[0]!='\n') {
            val = atoi(buf);
            break;
        }
    }
    free(buf);

    return val;
}

float determinant(int tam, float matrix[][tam])
{


    float s = 1, det = 0, b[tam][tam];

    int i, j, m, n, c;

    if (tam == 1)

      {

       return (matrix[0][0]);

      }

    else

      {

       det = 0;

       for (c = 0; c < tam; c++)

         {

          m = 0;

          n = 0;

          for (i = 0;i < tam; i++)

            {

              for (j = 0 ;j < tam; j++)

                {

                  b[i][j] = 0;

                  if (i != 0 && j != c)

                   {
                     b[m][n] = matrix[i][j];

                     if (n < (tam - 2))

                      n++;

                     else

                      {

                       n = 0;
                       m++;

                       }

                     }

                 }

               }

            det = det + s * (matrix[0][c] * determinant( tam - 1,b));
            s = -1 * s;
            }
      }

      return (det);
}


 void cofactor( int tam,float num[][tam])

 {

   float b[tam][tam], fac[tam][tam];

    int p, q, m, n, i, j;

    float x = 0;


  for (q = 0;q < tam; q++)

  {

    for (p = 0;p < tam; p++)

    {

     m = 0;

     n = 0;

 for (i = 0;i < tam; i++)

 {

   for (j = 0;j < tam; j++)

    {

      if (i != q && j != p)

      {
        b[m][n] = num[i][j];

        if (n < (tam - 2))

         n++;

        else

         {

           n = 0;

           m++;

           }

        }

    }

  }

  x = pow(-1, q + p) * determinant( tam - 1,b);

  fac[p][q] = x;
}

}

 transpose(tam,num, fac);

}

  void transpose(int tam,float num[][tam], float fac[][tam])

 {

  int i, j;

  float b[tam][tam], inverse[tam][tam], d;



   for (i = 0;i < tam; i++)



  {

     for (j = 0;j < tam; j++)

       {

         b[i][j] = fac[j][i];

        }

    }

      d = determinant(tam,num);



     for (i = 0;i < tam; i++)

    {

     for (j = 0;j < tam; j++)

       {

        inverse[i][j] = b[i][j] / d;

        }

    }

       printf("\n\n\nThe inverse of matrix is : \n");

       for (i = 0;i < tam; i++)

    {

     for (j = 0;j < tam; j++)

       {

         printf("\t%f", inverse[i][j]);

        }

        printf("\n");

     }

}

    int verify_Size(int line){

        if((line > 0) && (line <= 6))
        {
            return 1;
        }

    return 0;
    }


    int create_Matrix(int LINE){

        int matrix[LINE][LINE];
        float aux[LINE][LINE];

        printf("\n\n\nPle:", (LINE * LINE));
        printf("\n--------------------------------\n");

        for(int i=0;i<LINE;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<LINE;j++)
            {
                printf("Value[%d][%d]: ",i,j);

                matrix[i][j] = validate();
            }
        }

        printf("\n\nYour Bidimensional Matrix is:");
        printf("\n--------------------------------\n");


        for(int i=0;i < LINE;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j< LINE;j++)
            {
                printf("\t%2d",matrix[i][j]);
                aux[i][j] = (float) matrix[i][j];

        }
        printf("\n");
    }

      float d = determinant(LINE,aux);

       printf("\n\nDeterminante Main: %f \n",d);

       if (d == 0)

       printf("\nInverse of Entered Matrix is not possible\n");

       else

        cofactor(LINE,aux);

       return 0;

}


    int main(){

    int flag,line;

    do{
        printf("Enter the order of the Matrix:\n");
        printf("-------------------------------\n");

        printf("Lines: ");
        line = validate();


        if(verify_Size(line)== 1)
        {
            create_Matrix(line);

        }else{

            printf("\nMatrix must to be till 6 X 6!\n");

            flag = 0;

        }

    }while(flag != 1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `I want to remove the function's prototype at the beginning` Why?

Comment: Because I have a function which allows the user to create a matrix NxN so that I don't know the matrix size before the user create the matrix.

Comment: The code you posted looks to be hardcoded to 3x3. Fiddling with the prototypes won't change that.

Comment: Yeah that's the idea I want to remove the prototype and pass the matrices as parameters till I find the inverse matrix

Comment: I'd start by running your code through a formatter. I tred to get it all in the markdown code block for starters.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are finding the inverse matrix by [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule). While it works Ok for 2x2 or 3x3 matrix sizes, the hard part about implementing Cramer's rule generally is evaluating determinants. If you compute an NxN determinant following the definition, the computation is recursive and has factorial O(N!) computational complexity ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Calculation)).

I suggest switching to another algorithm. LUP factorization is fast and relatively simple, and [Wikipedia has an example implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition#C_code_examples).